# JQuery: How to perform a "push" slide, not a slide up?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I using the following JQuery:

```
$("#pushSlideDiv").slideDown("fast");
```

However, this creates a "slide" effect. Meaning, if I do a `slidedown`, this makes the underlining DIV reveal it's self from a top-to-bottom reveal.

I want a "push" effect, where the slidedown instead reveals as though the div is being pushed onto the page ... where you first see the bottom of the div.

How can I do this with JQuery?

**UPDATE**:

[This isn't a great example](http://aaronweyenberg.com/demos/voteflipper/demo.html), but it does show a push effect that I'm trying to accomplish vs a "slide" effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's animate() method.

```
$("div").css({top:0}).animate({top:500},{duration: 50});
```

This will set your div initially at top:0 and animate it to top:500 over a duration of 0.5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You want jquery ui!  Check it out: http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/#default

Here's a closer look: 
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the slide effect for .show and .hide in jQuery UI.

[Jquery UI Show Demo](http://jqueryui.com/docs/show/)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a combination of the Slide effect and the Clip effect.

Not sure what that effect would be to use.